# using knockback to bind 2d array changes - Uncaught Observable: key is missing

Tags: knockout.js, knockback.js

I am trying to use knockbackjs (knockoutjs + backbonejs) where the model is a 2d array )ie table, and the viewModel is binded using foreach to a table html tag, so I will get an observable table, each click on a cell will send the entire 2d array to the api.

I've been looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305655/the-simplest-example-of-knockback-js-working-with-a-restful-webservice-such-as-s) and [that](http://jszip.org/quickstart-knockback/) examples with a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888042/table-is-not-refreshed-with-knockoutjs) I've asked and got to something like this:

```
    //model
    var GameModel = Backbone.Model.extend({ urlRoot: '/game' });

    //viewmodel
    var GameViewModel = function (game) {

        this.board = kb.observable(game, [
                         [ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0)],
                         [ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0)],
                         [ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0)]
                     ]);
    };

    var model = new GameModel({ id: 1 });
    var gameViewModel = new GameViewModel(model);
    ko.applyBindings(gameViewModel);
```

but I get ' Uncaught Observable: key is missing ' on the line starting with

```
this.board = kb.observable(game, [
```

How can I fix this?
Is there a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send an object to the observable, I'd have thought, whereas you are just sending through a list of parameters.

You either need to just send the array in, or else make it an object, e.g.:

```
this.board = kb.observable(
{
    'game': game,
    'board': [
        [ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0)],
        [ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0)],
        [ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0), ko.observable(0)]
    ]
});
```

Comment: it gives me this error- options is missing. when I've put some options I get the error key is missing. which key am I missing?

Comment: What is options referring to? Is that something you are binding to in the html?

Comment: options that are in the kb.observable function parameters. http://kmalakoff.github.io/knockback/tutorial_kb_observable.html , it fails before the binding part.